# FreeMarker Current Date Comparison

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to do date comparisons against the current date in a freemarker template without passing the current date into the template?

Answer (score 22):

From [FreeMarker 2.3.17](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_17.html) on you can use the new special variable [`.now`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html):

```
[#assign foo = .now > yesterday?datetime]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me . My version of freemarker template is 2.3.20 .<#assign futDate="2011-05-16T21:32:13Z" >
<#assign foo = .now > futDate?datetime> . foo is becoming null

Answer (score 2):

Better way to compare two dates in freemarker is to find the difference between two dates.

```
<#assign difference = (custom_date?long / 86400000)?round - (.now?long / 86400000)?round />
```

If the `difference` is greater than 0, it's a future date, if it equal it is same date, if it less than, it is previous date

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this issue.

I was comparing 2 dates

```
[#assign .now?date lte today?date]
```

(they both were **10/10/2019**)

but for some reason it was false even though it was equal, so what I had to do was

```
[#assign .now?string["dd/MM/yyyy"]?date lte today?date]
```

Answer (score -8):

**NO**

Freemarker is a templating library, there isn't a *today* variable.

But you can pass a `new Date()` Java Object to the template.

Comment: You should consider updating or deleting this answer, as it is now incorrect

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be a current date in principle, but it was a so frequent request, `.now` was added despite it's so dirty.