# How to display the current date & time in the Freemarker template section of smooks?

Tags: freemarker

I am able to display the contents of my incoming XML file using smooks in the freemarker template, but I want to add Current Date & time of my local system to identify the execution of my program.

```
<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="CreditCard">
    <ftl:template><!--        <BalanceInquiryRequest>
        <TransactionId>${BalanceInquiryRequest.TransactionId}</<TransactionId>
        <ConfigurationId>${BalanceInquiryRequest.ConfigurationId}</ConfigurationId>
        <CardNumberr>${.vars["GiftCard"].CardNumber}</CardNumberr>
        <ExpirationDate>${.vars["GiftCard"].ExpirationDate}</ExpirationDate>
        <SecurityCode>${.vars["GiftCard"].SecurityCode}</SecurityCode>
       *****************************
Here I want to display the current Date & time 
    </BalanceInquiryRequest>
    --></ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
```

Can you tell me how can I add current date & time in the XML without having an entry in the incoming XML.

Answer (score 8):

use .now, they introduced it some time ago, no need for java

Comment: Here is an example: `<#assign dateTime=.now> <p>${dateTime?iso_local}.</p>`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373941/freemarker-current-date-comparison). The short answer, you need to pass in Java.

Comment: It isn't so anymore... 2.3.17 has introduced the special variable `.now`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it since XML like Freemarker are template engines, not objects. You have to pass it into the java object as `new Date();`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a short groovy script in the Smooks configuration file to populate a bean in the beancontext with today's date. Then the freemarker script could use the value from that bean.

Edit: You can read more about Groovy and Smooks here: http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.3:Smooks_v1.3_User_Guide#Groovy_Scripting

You probably want to use methods from http://www.milyn.org/javadoc/v1.2/smooks-cartridges/javabean/org/milyn/javabean/repository/BeanRepository.html and do something similar to:

```
  <g:groovy executeOnElement="xxx">
    <g:script>
    <!--
    addBean("date", new Date());
    -->
    </g:script>
</g:groovy>
```

You should then be able to access the "date" bean in your freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without .now and you don't have to pass in new Date.
I'm having to work with old freemarker at the moment and did this instead..

```
<#assign dateNow = Static["java.util.Calendar"].getInstance().getTime()?datetime />
```